# How to add html form to asp:PlaceHolder (missing form tag)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms, asp.net-placeholder

I have to add simple form to a asp:PlaceHolder

```
<form action="https://www...." method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden"...
<input type="hidden"...
<input type="image" ...name="submit">
</form>
```

In `PageLoad()` I added:

```
data = "<form action=...."
this.myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(data));
```

When page rendered page source is:

```
<input type="hidden"...
<input type="hidden"...
<input type="image"...name="submit"...
<img alt=""...
```

As you can see **no form tag**?
But I am sure that `data` variable contains "`<form ...`".
Is there any other way to add form to  `placeholder` maybe I use wrong approach?

Comment: Can't you just edit the .aspx file?

Comment: No I have to add this form dynamical

Comment: Direct use a Literal to add the form, and the rest data.

Comment: @Aristos I'm sorry I don't understand what is your advice?

Comment: If this form tag is rendered within another form, e.g. within a masterpage then it will likely be removed.

Comment: Yes that's what happened. But if I add this form where I want placeholder it works fine. It makes problem only when I try to add it to placeholder from code behind.

Comment: If it works within a placeholder, then why not just use inline server tags to pass in the form values you need to post, e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="test" value="<%= myVariable %>" />`

Comment: @DGibbs how can I pass value from code behind to this `<%= myVariable %>`?

Comment: Create a variable named `myVariable` and set it's value in the code behind..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to add this answer maybe will help someone.
When I add "`<form...`" form tag is not added but
If I add "`<form></form><form...`" to palceholder then it works.
I don't understand why but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding a form dynamically you should add those to the asp file. like this:

```
<form action="https://www" method="post" target="_top">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

then you can add any object on the placeholder.